# SQL extract portion of blob

Tags: sql, xml, blob

I'm having issues to extract data from a blob field in my database.
the content of the blob looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><preferences><timezone>Asia/Singapore</timezone><displayscheduleinusertimezone>N</displayscheduleinusertimezone><locale>English</locale><dateformat>d/MMM/yyyy</dateformat><timeformat>hh:mm aaa</timeformat><longformat>Long_01</longformat>
```

I want to extract the string between `<locale>` and `</locale>` (in our case that would be "English).

So far I have only been able to extract the full content of the blob by using this code:

```
SELECT trim(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(preferences,2000,1)))
from User_Preferences
```

Any quick and dirty trick to make my above line work for my need? :)

Comment: please tag your RDBMS (vendor and version)